# Copy 2D array to another Vba module

Tags: vba

Hello ı created tableData() 2d array in named "list" module by getlist() function. I want to copy tableData() array to main sub. I think firstly ı have to call and run function in main sub  afterwards copy. But ıdk how to do it could you help me? I hope problem is clear.

```
'list module
Public Function getlist()
Dim tableData() As String
End Function

'Main Module
Sub Main()
Dim partlist() As String
partlist() = list.tableData() ' ıdk :)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

No need to use global variables.

(1) You need to assign a return value to a function. In VBA, this is done by assigning the return value to the "function" itself.

```
Public Function getlist() As String()
    'any operations with array tableData() 
   Dim tableData() As String
   (...)
   getlist = tableData
End Function
```

(2) When you call the function, assign the return value to your main procedure

```
Sub Main()
   Dim partList() As String
   partlist = getlist
   (...)
End Sub
```

Comment: ı couldn't do it as you type.

Comment: What do you mean with your comment?  Why couldn't you do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Public tableData() As String
Public Function getlist()
'any operations with array tableData() 
End Function

Sub Main()
Dim partlist() As String
partlist() = list.tableData() ' ıdk :)
End Sub
```

Comment: Call list.getlist If ı dont call function its copy empty array.